# How to ensure commit policy of "code must be compile" when using git staging?

Tags: git, policy

Suppose the scenario, I modified two source files, but only staging one of them, and execute a commit (local) This particular commit will represent a state of source which nowhere exist in the file system, so I can not test if it is compiles or not. (which is required as commit policy)

Reverting to that particular commit locally (then compile) will result the not staged file(s)'s changes lost.
Without pushing it to the remote I can not clone it to an other folder to test if compiles, however pushing it to the remote will make the not verified source available for the team, so make things worst.

The only workflow I can find out is, to create a local (backup) copy of the current sources, then revert the local repo to the commit, (accepting the not committed changes lost (the not staged source file)), compile, if not compiles, then copy back from the backup, modify, take a guess, *amend*, still not staging what I did not wanted to commit in the first place, then repeat this cycle until the reverted files are compile.

**Question**

It sounds so overcomplicated, that either

- a) I miss something,
- b) the staging with files requiring strict consistency with each other (source files) the staging is not a usable practice. The modification on multiple files must be atomic (a la ACID).

Comment: Make as many **local commits** as you like, even if they don’t build - the only thing that matters is that your code builds in the **squashed commit** that will be merged from your final submitted PR.

Comment: You misunderstand the nature of commit policies: they’re (intended) to only be for the merged commits from feature-branches. Commit policies are *not* about your local commits (otherwise how would anyone get anything done?)

Comment: …that said, why aren’t you squashing/appending/rebasing?

Comment: It is true, that local commit will not break others work, however it is still exist, and even further commits will compile, still the remote repo will be polluted with unusable not compiling commits. What would be the purpose to not staging a file, keeping that file changes back during a series of *local* commits, then finally publishing it in a commit then pushing all commits to the remote? The whole not staging adn keeping some changes to see others became meaningless, if the whole sits in local. Also the must compile is a must every pushed commit, except in private branches.

Comment: “still the remote repo will be polluted with unusable not compiling commits ” - That’s why I said *squashed commits*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git stash push -ak` to undo all changes to the working directory which haven't been committed or staged yet. Then you can do your testing, commit your staged changes, and then `git stash pop` to restore your work in progress. The `git stash` documentation even suggests this usecase ("Testing partial commits" under EXAMPLES).

Comment: Many thanks. The point is the -k (--keep-index) if I understand correctly

Comment: @g.pickardou yes, and the `--all` which even stashes changes to untracked and ignored files, so that what you're testing is really what you will commit.

Comment: thx again.......